# Missing trailing slash in markup of links in comments and chat

Tags: discussion, comments, chat, markdown, hyperlinks

I noticed a bug in the markdown of hyperlinks in comments and chat with a trailing slash. The link will work correctly, but the markup shows the link without the trailing slash.

So if you write something like:

`http://www.example.com/index/` it will show like `http://www.example.com/index`

[Check a chat example here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18539742#18539742) and [a comment example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25502376/zend-framework-2-htaccess-url-issue/25509368?noredirect=1#comment39881867_25509368)

Comment: I think a bug by definition has to actually interfere with function. This doesn't do that. It looks like a design choice.

Comment: @balpha how come this is a discussion? OP think it's a bug, so isn't it more appropriate to just mark it as [tag:status-bydesign] or [tag:status-declined]?